# lightning:recordViewForm throwing error if update records fetched from server

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-recordviewform

I have a use case in which I have to display Opportunity fields(stored in custom metadata type) using lightning:recordViewForm.

On initial load I do API call which returns Opportunity Id and some other details in response, I stored API response in List type attribute of Component and also stored fields in List type attribute of Component.
here is the example:-

```
<aura:component controller="TopOpportunitiesController"  access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="opprtunityFields" default="[]" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityData" default="[]" type="object[]"/>
    <ui:inputSelect value="{!v.selectedOwner}"  class="usersFilter" change="{!c.reloadData}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="All Opportunities" label="All Opportunities"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="My Opportunities" label="My Opportunities"/>
    </ui:inputSelect>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.opportunityData.length > 0}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunityData}" var="opd" indexVar="index">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-show-inline_block ">
                <a class="oppName" href="{!'/'+opd.opportunityId}" target="_top" style="text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;padding:0" data-id="{!opd.opportunityId}" onclick="{!c.onOppClick}">
                    {!opd.company_name}
                </a>
            </div>
            <lightning:recordViewForm  
                                      recordId="{!opd.opportunityId}" 
                                      objectApiName ="Opportunity">

                <aura:iteration items="{!v.topOpprtunityFieldsConfig}" var="OFC">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!OFC.fieldAPI != undefined}">
                        <div class="opportunityDetailsRow">
                            <span class="healthHeader" >
                                {!OFC.fieldLabel}:
                            </span>
                            <div class="opportunityStage">
                                <lightning:outputField  variant="label-hidden" class="slds-show_inline-block"  fieldName="{!OFC.fieldAPI}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aura:if>
                </aura:iteration>


            </lightning:recordViewForm>
        </aura:iteration>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Using reloadData controller method I re-do the API call based on the selected value, once I call reloadData get the following error and do not display data even though I have records:-
[image]

Please correct me if I am doing wrong or you have any other approach to display fields of Opportunity where fields are dynamic.